# Load keras model with tflearn

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tflearn

I've trained models in Keras and I need to load this models in code made in Tflearn.

---

I can save the Keras trained models with the line:

```
model.save('my_model.hdf5') #keras
```

It saves the architecture and weights of the trained model.

or the line:

```
model.save_weights('my_model.hdf5') #keras
```

It saves only the weights of the trained model.

---

**The purpose is to load the model into tflearn using for example this line:**

```
model.load ('example.tflearn') #tflearn
```

This line just load the weights, requires that the architecture be passed before.

**I tried loading the files generated by .save and .save_weights from Keras with .load of tflearn but it did not work.**